# How to handle Risk in TFS scrum templates

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, agile, scrum, cmmi

In the TFS CMMI template, I can find the Risk work item and it's very useful for us.
But I couldn't find this work item in the Scrum and the Agile template.
Please let me know how to handle the Risk within the TFS Scrum and Agile template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a Risk Work Item is mostly considered an unnecessary overhead and is not required to meet CMMI. Since Risks don't change often, and should not abound, I would keep them on a list on the Team wall. If you have so many risks that you and your team cant remember them then that should set alarm bells off!

Wherever you keep them they should be visible and accessible by the engineers.

Option 1: Stickies on the wall (best)
Option 2: In Excel, printed and on the wall
Option 3: Create your own Risk work item